# How to use sparse matrix in python hcluster?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, linkage, hcluster

I'm trying to use hcluster library in python. I have no enough python knowledges to use sparse matrix in hcluster. Please help me anybody. So, that what I'm doing:

```
import os.path
import numpy
import scipy
import scipy.io 
from hcluster import squareform, pdist, linkage, complete 
from hcluster.hierarchy import linkage, from_mlab_linkage 
from numpy import savetxt 
from StringIO import StringIO
```

data.dmp contains matrix looks like:

```
  A B C D
A 0 1 0 1 
B 1 0 0 1 
C 0 0 0 0 
D 1 1 0 0
```

and contains only upper-right part of matrix. I don't know how to spell it in english correctly :) so, all numbers upper than main diagonal
so data.dmp contains :    1 0 1, 0 1 , 0

```
f = file('data.dmp','r')  
s = StringIO(f.readline()).getvalue()
f.close()

matrix = numpy.asarray(eval("["+s+"]"))
```

by unknown reason for me, hcluster uses inverted values,  for example I use 0 if A!=C,and use 1 if A == D

```
sqfrm = squareform(matrix)
Y = pdist(sqfrm, metric="cosine")
```

linkage Y

```
Z = linkage(Y, method="complete")
```

So, matrix Z is what I need (if I correctly used hcluster?)

But I have next problems:

1. I want to use sparse matrix for
   the huge amount of input data, cause it's time
   consuming to generate input data
   like now, I need to import data to
   python from another language, thats
   why I need read text file. Please
   kindly, python guru's suggest how to
   make it?
2. To people that used python
   hcluster, I need to process huge
   amount of data, hundreds of rows,
   it's possible to do in hcluster?
   This algorithm realy produce correct
   HAC?

Thank you for reading, I appreciate any help!

Comment: I can't imagine how this code can work, as written. For a start, `import scipy.io from hcluster` should be `from hcluster import scipy.io`. The first alternative is not syntactic.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. I rewrite import lines. Cause formatting in ruby style firstly :)

Answer (score 2):

Represent the inputs each as a dictionary, from feature name to value. Zeros are not present in the dictionary.

Compute the Y matrix yourself, not using the `hcluster.pdist`. The following code does sparse squared-error. Squared-error is equivalent to cosine distance **IF** you l2-normalize all feature vectors.

```
def sqrerr(repr1, repr2):
    """
    Compute the sqrerr between two reprs.
    The reprs are each a dict from feature to feature value.
    """
    keys = frozenset(repr1.keys() + repr2.keys())
    sqrerr = 0.
    for k in keys:
        diff = repr1.get(k, 0.) - repr2.get(k, 0.)
        sqrerr += diff * diff
    return sqrerr
```

You should call sqrerr for every Y[i,j] element you want to compute.

Make Y a square matrix, and make sure that Y[i,j] == Y[j,i]. Use method `hcluster.squareform` to convert Y to a form that is good for `hcluster.linkage`.